# Behavioral differences between online/offline events in Android and Windows chrome browser

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, offline, navigator

I am developing a project with reactjs and during the project I need to check the internet connection to warn the user if the internet is down while working with the program. For this purpose, I have defined an online event listener and an offline event listener in the App.js file to show the relevant message to the user if these events occur. This is done correctly on devices running the Android operating system, but on devices running the Windows operating system, these events do not appear to be generated and no message is displayed. Is the definition of online and offline listener alone not enough?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you checked [canisue.com](https://www.caniuse.com/online-status) to see which support it?

Comment: I am using version 89 of Chrome browser in Windows. It seems that it should support.